# Can I remove "&& isset" in a php form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have got the following form to work using PHP and JavaScript to validate... 
The problem is, each time I want to update the inputs in the form I need to also update the `&& isset` and `$input = $_REQUEST['input name'];` in the PHP! Are these important? there is no way to make the whole process easier?! please advise

PHP:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      ob_start();

      if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['email'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['message'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['number'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['date'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['select'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['radio'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['checkbox'])
      && isset($_REQUEST['token'])){

         if($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']){
            $response = "0";
         } else {
            $_SESSION['token'] = "";
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
            $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
            $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
            $select = $_REQUEST['select'];
            $radio = $_REQUEST['radio'];
            $checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox'];

            $to = "";
            $subject = "New Message From: $name";
            $message = "Name: $name<br/>
                        number: $number<br/>
                        date: $date<br/>
                        select: $select<br/>
                        radio: $radio<br/>
                        checkbox: $checkbox<br/>
                        Email: $email<br/>
                        Message: $message";

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
            $mailed = (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));

            if( isset($_REQUEST['ajax']))$response = ($mailed) ? "1" :
            "0"; else $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" :
            "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
            echo $response;
         }

      } else {
         echo "Form data error!";
      }

      ob_flush();
      die();
   }
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<?php
               $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
               $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            ?>

            <!--Contact Form-->
            <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="contact.php"  method="post">
               <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
               <input name="ajax" type="hidden" value="1">

               <div class="name">
                  <p>Your Name</p>
                  <input name="name" class="required" autocomplete="off">
               </div>

               <div class="email-address">
                  <p>Email Address</p>
                  <input name="email" class="required email" autocomplete="off">
               </div>

               <div class="message">
                  <p>Message</p>
                  <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="required min3"></textarea>
               </div>

               <div class="number">
                  <p>Phone Number</p>
                  <input name="number" class="number" autocomplete="off">
               </div>

               <div class="date">
                  <p>Date <small>(dd/mm/yyyy)</small></p>
                  <input name="date" class="required date calendar" autocomplete="off">
               </div>

               <div class="dropdown">
                  <select name="select" class="required">
                     <option value="">Select</option>
                     <option value="DropdownA">DropdownA</option>
                     <option value="DropdownB">DropdownB</option>
                  </select>
               </div>

               <div class="radio">
                  <p>Radios:</p>
                  <label><input name="radio" type="radio" value="male" class="required">Male</label>
                  <label><input name="radio" type="radio" value="female" class="required">Female</label>
               </div>

               <div class="checkbox">
                  <p>Checkboxs:</p>
                  <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="OptionA" class="required">Option A</label>
                  <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="OptionB" class="required">Option B</label>
               </div>

               <div>
                  <p></p>
                  <input name="" class="required number spamcheck">
               </div>

               <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: why not make the validation process only with jquery for example ? Would save you the mess. But yes in your case they are important.

Comment: Because it's easy to circumvent the client-side validation.

Comment: Never do the validation only on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to check if variables are set, before using them. Otherwise your script will raise errors for undefined variables. E.g. You each time will try to check if `$_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']` but it will give you errors, because there's no form submitted (or however the request is sent) with `token` name, that's why you do need to check it before that.

Anyway, for multiple `isset()` you can use a comma separator

```
if(isset($var, $var2, $var3...))
```

instead of

```
if(isset($var) && isset($var2)...))
```

Also,, if you session token is not initialized too (completely new request to the page), and no request is send to it, your `if()` statement will return false, thus triggering the `mail()` function. So, in you particular case it's more than necessary to have a check before using them in mail form.

Comment: is it somthing like this what you mean? 'if(isset(
         $_REQUEST['name'],
         $_REQUEST['email'],
         $_REQUEST['message'],
         $_REQUEST['date'],
         $_REQUEST['select'],
         $_REQUEST['radio'],
         $_REQUEST['checkbox'],
         $_REQUEST['token']
      )){'

Comment: Thank you just did it, however I am trying to make everything simpler for example there is no way to combine these with the once just underneath them? right under "f($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']){
            $response = "0";
         } else {"

Comment: These are two different validations. You can combine them until reaching non-readable code. Better don't. You can encapsulate them in functions, in order to avoid nested if/else blocks.

Comment: Will leave it then, okay do you think my form is secure enough? I have used Token, and I have added a math security question to prevent spam, I don't want to use reCapture - any advise? please

Comment: Do you have a validation of the posted Email address? Because one can add not only email address but something different which will be added to `$headers`. This way can change the content type and all the things that can be manipulated from the Headers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47803/discussion-between-loai-and-royal-bg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are important. Lots of ways to make the process easier though. You might want to look at a simple framework like [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) (the [forms component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) can be used independently of the whole framework).

Be aware that you'll probably get a massive amount of spam with that form. Add a captcha like [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the validation is important but you can simplify your code. I would use an array to define the required fields. It's easy to maintain and much less code.

```
$requiredFields = array('name', 'email', 'message', 'number');
$valid = true;

foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$field])) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($valid) {
    // Do the stuff
} else {
    echo "Form data error!";
}
```

If you want to check if the current field actually contains something add empty() to the condition:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST[$field]) || empty($_REQUEST[$field])) {
```

I think the second part where you assign the post values to separate variables is actually unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Please can you post a the code here? https://gist.github.com I am going to struggle to put this together